# Logic trouble with loop

Tags: c#

I am creating a windows form that is a random number guessing game. I've made these before in C++ and never had an issue, however I have a big one here- I have no idea how to get the user back to input a number after the loop has began running. Here is my code:

```
    private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int guess = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int accumulator = 0; // accumulator

        Random rand = new Random();
        int number = rand.Next(1, 100);
        txtAnswer.Focus();

        while (guess != number)
        {
            guess = int.Parse(txtAnswer.Text);
            if (guess < number)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Too Low! Guess again!");
                txtAnswer.Text = "";
                txtAnswer.Focus();
                count++;
                accumulator++;
            }
            else if (guess > number)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Too High! Try again!");
                txtAnswer.Text = "";
                txtAnswer.Focus();
                count++;
                accumulator++;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Correct! you guessed the number in " + accumulator + " tries!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I just filled the while loop arguments with something for you guys, even though i know it won't work. Basically, I need to run the loop, get feedback (if the users guess was too high or low) then get the user to be able to input another number BEFORE the loop runs again. I don't know how to get that to happen with a text box control which is where the input will be. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you expecting the user to put another number in the txtAnswer text box?

Comment: yes once the loop iterates once and the user receives feedback, i need them to input another number into the textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not loop inside in the btnGuess_Click. Instead you need to store the state (the number, count, and the accumulator variables) in the scope of the form itself.

Initialize the random number when the form loads, or using some kind of start button.

Then inside the guess button handler, read the text box value and compare it to the number variable, such as what you are doing currently.

Answer (score 0):

What you are building is more a console style application. So there is 1 main loop that is executing all the code.

In forms applications it is an event driven environment. So the user gets a form, presses a button, the form is evaluated and then the method handling ends.

So you have on a class level some variables for counts, in the constructor you add the initialization and the method for submit will be something like

```
 private void btnGuess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //Increment counters
    //Check
    //Show feedback
    //Leave the button click code
  }
```

For some more info, check this out: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492132.aspx